# proving the non-axiomatizable of a class of L-structures

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm studying the model theory notes of [https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~anush/Courses/2016F.Math571.MT/Henson--van%20den%20Dries.pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Eanush/Courses/2016F.Math571.MT/Henson--van%20den%20Dries.pdf) for model theory. I'm finding it difficult with the 6.11 exercise:

Let $L$ be the first order language with two binary function symbols ∩ and ∪, a unary function symbol c, and two constant symbols 0 and 1. For each set S let P(S) denote the $L$-structure based on the power set of S. That is, the underlying set of P(S) is the collection of all subsets of S, we interpret ∩,∪,c as intersection, union, and complement, respectively, and we interpret 0,1 as ∅,S, respectively. Let K be the class of all $L$- structures that are isomorphic to P(S) for some set S. Show that K is not axiomatizable.

I think the solution involves arguing that K is axiomatizable and then finding a contradiction. If anyone can give a comprehensive answer I would appreciate it.

Comment: The chapter is about the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem. You should use it. Notice that there are no countably infinite powersets. Can you construct a countably infinite model of the $L$-theory of $K$?

Comment: I'm sorry, just confused. I can't really understand how it all plays out in the general abdtract case?

Comment: "I think of S as an infinite dimensional vector space. The power set will also be countably infinite." Really?

Comment: What you wrote just now makes no sense. How can Card(S) be both aleph_0 and 2^(aleph_0)? And 2^(aleph_0) is not countably infinite!

Comment: Terrible typos. I meant Card(P(S)) would be 2^(aleph_0). And, ok I  think I get it 2^(aleph_0)=aleph_1 is not countably finite (countably finite doesn't exist).

Comment: We cannot prove $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$: this is the continuum hypothesis! But of course Cantor proved that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable. I have no idea what you mean by "countably finite doesn't exist".

Comment: Of course. I just meant that when I said the Cardinality of S is both  aleph_0 and 2^(aleph_0), this was simply a typo. "We cannot prove 2^ℵ0=ℵ1" yes of course. "countably finite doesn't exist" I meant countably finite powerset doesn't exist which Zhen wrote as a hint and the proofs are available in stack.

Comment: You mean "countably infinite", then - i.e., there is no countably infinite powerset. I'm just encouraging you to put a little effort into writing precisely.

Comment: Yes, that's another typo among many. Yes I should've been more considerate of the precision of writing.  New at typing mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for a contradiction that the class $K$ is axiomatisable by some first-order theory $T$. Consider the structure $P(\mathbb{N})$, which is in $K$. This structure is infinite (it has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$). By the downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem there is then a countable elementary substructure $A \preceq P(\mathbb{N})$. Being an elementary substructure means in particular that $A$ satisfies the same sentences as $P(\mathbb{N})$. So because $P(\mathbb{N}) \models T$ we also have $A \models T$. That would mean that $A$ is in the class $K$. By definition of $K$ we then have that $A$ is of the form $P(S)$ for some infinite set $S$. Because $|S| \geq \aleph_0$ we have:
$$
|A| = |P(S)| = 2^{|S|}  \geq 2^{\aleph_0}.
$$
But this contradicts that $A$ is countable. So we find our contradiction and conclude that the class $K$ cannot be first-order axiomatisable.